# How to disable specify rows in objectlistview

Tags: objectlistview

There

I want to disable some rows in objectlistview (Ver. 2.9)

Code:

```
private void olvPatientstockedOrders_FormatRow(object sender, FormatRowEventArgs e)
    {           
        CServerOrder order = (CServerOrder)e.Model;          
        if(order.OrderControl.ToUpper().Contains("DC"))
        {
            olvPatientstockedOrders.DisableObject(e.Model);        
        }     
    }
```

But I get exceptions on code "olvPatientstockedOrders.DisableObject(e.Model);
and there is no details info

[image]

Comment: Maybe `DisableObject()` internally calls `FormatRow` so its stuck in an endless loop? -> StackOverflowException. Would make sense, since DisableObject() potentially changes the look/format of the row.

Comment: @Rev1.0, thanks for your answer, I move the DisableObject() to another method, it does works.

Comment: Glad it helped, I posted the comment as an answer so you can mark this resolved.

Comment: which method did you move it to?  I tried setting the rows to disabled right after I set the object to the treelistview but it's not working.

Comment: nevemind, I found out how to do it right after I set the objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DisableObject()` internally calls `FormatRow` (since DisableObject() potentially changes the look/format of the row), so it is stuck in an endless loop and causing a StackOverflowException (like the exception dialog suggests).